# HttpURLConnection - get the normal instead of the mobile website in servlet

Tags: java, http, url, servlets

I have the following HttpURLConnection in my Servlet:

```
url = new URL("http://www.example.com/parameter1/parameter2/...");
        HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();  
        c.setRequestMethod("GET");
        c.setReadTimeout(2000);

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(c.getInputStream(),"UTF8"));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        res.append(inputLine);  
        }
```

My Problem is, that the Website Server gives me the mobile website and not the normal website like i get in a normal browser.
What(and how) do i have to send with this GET request, the get the normal website from the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling

```
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2049.0 Safari/537.36");
```

It will set the user agent property to Chrome (desktop) browser.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! Set another User-Agent by typing

```
c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
```

Or whatever.